How to rotate an image with a certain angle in C#
I am trying to code a method that accepts the direction of rotation and the angle with which to make the rotation of the Image object in the Picture Box but am having difficulty completing it. The method takes an Image object, the angle of rotation and the direction whether clockwise or anti-clockwise as parameters and returns a manipulated Image object to the calling function. How do I achieve this in C#?
private Image RotateImage(Image image, double angle, string direction) {
    //TO DO
    //check the direction and proceed
    switch(direction) {
        case "clockwise":
            //do the computation for clockwise rotation and update the image
            break;
        case "anti-clockwise":
            //do the computation for anti-clockwise rotation and update the image
            break;
    }
    //return the image to the calling function
    return image;
}

I am using a timer to create the illusion of a fan rotating continuously and modifying the interval of the timer to control the speed of the fan as its just playing with the refresh rate of the image on the picture box control.

What type is "Image"? Depending on the framework (WinForms? WPF? Skia? WinUI?), the answer will probably be vastly different

@Lennart, the framework is windows forms and Image is the Image type in Windows Forms

Here are some ways to do it.

@Ralf, thanks testing the answer in the post

@Ralf, the image rendered is bigger than the picture box despite telling my picture box to stretch the image in the Size Mode property
